# Can we manually track that a notification was opened?

Tags: android, mobilepush-android, push-notification, tracking

I'm using Salesforce mobile push alongside with Firebase Messaging.

Since I'm building the notifications manually on FirebaseMessagingService, I'd like to know if there's a public method to track the opening events.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDKs support multiple push provider configurations.  Take a look at the documentation for such https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html

The piece of the puzzle that's going to be missing for you is the `messageId` if you're trying to track messages sent via Firebase in our system.

The troubleshooting docs might be helpful too https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

Additional Info (edits)

You can "wrap" your `PendingIntent` that will collect analytics for the message, but this would require testing and validation on your part as this isn't a "recommended" approach (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/7.2/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications/-notification-manager/redirect-intent-for-analytics.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, Bill, but that doesn't quite answer my question unfortunately. 

I already know how to show both notifications. However I wouldn't like to call `sdk.pushMessageManager.handleMessage(message)`. I build the notifications manually and I'd like to know how to track the openings of Marketing Cloud Mobile Push notifications manually like when these notifications are created using `handleMessage(message)` method above.

Thanks

Comment: Added another possibility.

Comment: Thanks, Bill! That sounds promising. I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: Bill, I was able to wrap my PendingIntent, but it still seems not to be working. I'm following exactly what is mentioned on https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html but on the UI of MobilePush it still shows 0% of opened notifications. Do I have to add analytics as well for that to work?

Comment: "Do I have to add analytics as well for that to work?"; you must enable analytics during the SDK's initialization if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, Bill. This was key to make it work. I believe the docs could be clearer about this aspect.