# Manually track open push open rates

Tags: mobile, mobilepush, analytics, mobilepush-android

we are building a flutter app and integratin the SFMC plugins with our own plugin. We try to keep as much coding as possible in flutter/dart and we are also using firebase messaging. We have setup everything to correctly show push notifications from SFMC without conflicting with the existing firebase setup. Now we also want to track open rates. For android this appears to be usually done with `NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics`.

However, because we already show the notification within flutter, I am looking for an option to just call a function informing SFMC about the opened notification. I was trying to just use the provided wrapper function, but failed to build an intent that prevents the notification from being shown again (notice the empty Intent()):

```kotlin
val builder = NotificationManager.getDefaultNotificationBuilder(
                           context,
                           notificationMessage,
                           NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context),
                           R.drawable.notification_icon
                       )
                       builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
                       
                       builder.setContentIntent(
                           NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(
                               context,
                               PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                   context,
                                   Random().nextInt(),
                                   Intent(),
                                   PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                               ),
                               notificationMessage,
                               true,
                           )
                       )
```

Is there any way to just call a track function or calling `NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics` without showing the notification again?

This thread also deals with this topic, but they still work with a PendingIntent within kotlin: [Can we manually track that a notification was opened?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316215/can-we-manually-track-that-a-notification-was-opened)

Comment: What version of the SDK?

Comment: Version 8 - i think even the latest. We just integrated it last month

Comment: Yeah, I asked that question and then immediately realized it doesn't matter, sorry. Why don't you let the SDK display the notification?

Comment: We are building a flutter app so we try to keep everything inside dart code. This also allows us to nicely reuse all code we have built for push management for FCM. 
If there is no other way I would probably try to display it via the SDK, but for us that means duplicate code (notification channels, translations) instead of just having a centralized place.

Comment: @BillMote do you have a suggestion how to solve this? Is there an API to mark a push as opened or a workaround to call the analytics function of the SDK without showing the push?

Comment: There is not a way to do this without the SDK.

Comment: OK, so there is also no way to call the same SDK function that the SDK must call internally? Is not possible to expose that function?

Comment: There is no way to do that currently.